# How to perform conditional updation of column values in Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a below dataframe is there any way to perform conditional addition of column values in pandas.

```
  emp_id    emp_name    City    months_worked   default_sal total_sal   jan feb mar apr may jun
    111     aaa         pune       2                    90  NaN          4  5   5   54  3   2
    222     bbb         pune       1                    70  NaN          5  4   4   8   3   4
    333     ccc       mumbai       2                   NaN  NaN          9  3   4   8   4   3
    444     ddd          hyd       4                   NaN  NaN          3  8   6   4   2   7
```

**What I want to achive**

- if city = pune default_sal should be updated in total_sal for ex for
  emp_id 111 total_salary should be 90
- if city!=pune then depending on months_worked value total salary
  should be updated.For ex for emp id 333 months_worked =2 So addition
  of jan and feb value should be updated as total_sal which is 9+3=12

**Desired O/P**

```
emp_id  emp_name    City    months_worked   default_sal total_sal   jan feb mar apr may jun
    111     aaa     pune       2                  90    90           4  5   5   54  3   2
    222     bbb     pune       1                  70    70           5  4   4   8   3   4
    333     ccc     mumbai     2                  NaN   12           9  3   4   8   4   3
    444     ddd      hyd       4                  NaN   21           3  8   6   4   2   7
```

Comment: Why does `111` have a total of `90` when they apparently worked for two months?

Comment: As city is Pune I want default salary to be updated as total salary not the addion of values of months worked.

Comment: Ok, this is pretty standard stuff in Pandas. `df.iloc[df['City'] == 'pune', 'total_sal'] = df['default_sal']` and similar for your other task. Have you made some attempts on this?

Answer (score 0):

Using `np.where` after create the help series

```
s1=pd.Series([df.iloc[x,6:y+6].sum() for x,y in enumerate(df.months_worked)],index=df.index)
np.where(df.City=='pune',df.default_sal,s1 )
Out[429]: array([90., 70., 12., 21.])

#df['total']=np.where(df.City=='pune',df.default_sal,s1 )
```